# How to convert this meta_query to sql?

Tags: wordpress

I have a working `meta_query` in my custom personal Wordpress Theme. I would like to convert it to an SQL Query but don't know how to translate it to WP SQL and add an additional sort parameter. Can someone help me converting this meta_query to WP SQL?

```
$metakey = "series";

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'series'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'   => -1
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `WP SQL`?

Comment: I mean something like this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$args` will converted to this `sql` query:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'series') 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

So, if you want it to use by [$wpdb database class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), your code will be:

```
$query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts 
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'series') 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC ";
```

You can use it in `templates` of WordPress. If going to use in some *plugin/function file* first call `$wpdb` from `global` scope ( or you'll get `undefined` warnings):

```
global $wpdb;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning to use normal sql queries.  Do make join the following tables.

wp_posts, wp_meta

Make SQL statement with this two tables relationship.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more precise?